# Installed application is third-party or not

Tags: android

How can I get the list of installed third-party applications on Android phone.

I am able to get the list of application with the code below but I want only third-party applications.

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
appInstalModel.setAppName(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString());
appInstalModel.setAppPkg(p.packageName);
appInstalModel.setAppVersionName(p.versionName);
```

Comment: What do you mean by third party? Not from Google? Not from you?

Comment: @Roflcoptr Installed onto system or installed by the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
    for (int i=0; i < apps.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((apps.get(i).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)
        {
            //System app
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think it should like this.                                       if ((apps.get(i).applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)
        {
            //System app
       }

Answer (score 7):

RoflcoptrException's answer is correct. But in some cases it won't give you all the installed third-party applications. `ApplicationInfo` also has flag `FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP` which is set

> If this application has been install as an update to a built-in system
>   application

On my smart phone such applications include Amazone Kindle, Adobe Reader, Slacker Radio and others. These applications did not come with the phone and were installed from Google Play Store. Thus, they can be considered as third-party apps.

So, you may also want to check `FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP` flag.

```
final PackageManager packageManager = _context.getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications = 
    packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : installedApplications)
{
    if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0)
    {
        // IS A SYSTEM APP
    }

    if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0)
    {
        // APP WAS INSTALL AS AN UPDATE TO A BUILD-IN SYSTEM APP
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#FLAG_SYSTEM) object will have the `FLAG_SYSTEM` flag unset. The [sdmove](http://code.google.com/p/sdmove/) program might have some sample code.

Comment: perfect. I have to look into it.

Comment: How can i clone the sdmove project?

Answer (score 2):

small changes in @Roflcoptr answer.

```
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
for (int i=0; i < apps.size(); i++)
{
    if ((apps.get(i).applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)
    {
         //System app
   }
}
```

Thanks @Roflcoptr for your answer.

Comment: I highly recommend changing this from `(XXX & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)` to `(XXX & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0)` or `(XXX & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM == ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)`. The 1 only works because FLAG_SYSTEM happens to be 1, but that's a hardcoded value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<PackageInfo> getInstalledAppList(Context context) {
        ArrayList<PackageInfo> packList = (ArrayList<PackageInfo>) context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        showLog("/n/n ********************** App List ********************");
        for (int i = 0; i < packList.size(); i++) {

            PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(i);
            if ((packInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                String appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();
                showLog(appName + "(" + packInfo.packageName + ")");
            } else {
                packList.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }

        showLog("List Size : " + packList.size());
        showLog("/n/n ********************** END ********************");
        return packList;
    }
```