# Is it possible to get application name when package is removed

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

This is part of my receiver class:

```
   Uri dataURI = intent.getData();
    String appPackage = (dataURI != null ? dataURI.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null);

    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
        UpdateUserGamesService.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED;
    }
    else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)) {
        UpdateUserGamesService.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED;
    }
```

Its working well. Is there a way to get the application name and not only the package name?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229219/android-get-application-name-not-package-name

Comment: I am trying to get a 3rd party application name, not my own application.

Comment: then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514663/installed-application-is-third-party-or-not

Comment: Like the title states the problem is for the removed.

Comment: Once you get name while adding ,you can use persistent storage for retrieving name later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `ApplicationInfo` class :

**Information you can retrieve about a particular application**. This corresponds to **information collected from the AndroidManifest.xml's  tag**.

Try this code to get third party application name :

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
    for (int i=0; i < apps.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((apps.get(i).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)
        {
              String appName =  (String) getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(apps.get(i));
             Log.i("App Name", appName);
       }
    }
```

Now your question is :

```
Is it possible to get application name when package is removed ?
```

Well i will suggest that get all application name and store it using Persistent Storage (**SqLite will be best**).

In future if any one removes package still you will have all information related to that application.

I hope this will help.

Comment: SQLite is not the quickest solution. better off implementing shared preferences.